# shell script checker files

Tags: linux, shell

```
#!/bin/sh
conf_file="backup_ips.txt"
# read the input file line by line
while IFS= read -r line;do
    IFS='|'
    read -ra fields <<< "$line"
    DB=${fields[0]}
    IP=${fields[1]}
    USER=${fields[2]}
    PWD=${fields[3]}
    FILE=$DB.sql
    # start to backup
    echo "Backup DB instance Name:'$DB'('$IP,$USER,$PWD') to file:'$FILE'"
    # check file exists
    if [ -e "$FILE" ]; then
        read -p "File '$FILE' already exists. Do you want to overwrite it?(y/n)" choice
        echo $choice
        case "$choice" in
        y|Y )
            echo "Overwriting file '$FILE'..."
            nohup mysqldump --single-transaction  --no-tablespaces --set-gtid-purged=OFF  -u$USER -p$PWD -h $IP --all-databases > $FILE &;;
        n|N )
            echo "Skipping file '$FILE'...";;
        * )
            echo "Invalid choice. Skipping file '$FILE'...";;
        esac
    else
        nohup mysqldump --single-transaction  --no-tablespaces --set-gtid-purged=OFF  -u$USER -p$PWD -h $IP --all-databases > $FILE &
    fi
done <"$conf_file"

read -p "File '$FILE' already exists. Do you want to overwrite it?(y/n)" choice     
echo $choice     
case "$choice" in
```

the $choice always shows empty value

Comment: I started fixing the formatting but realised the script is pretty long. Please fix it yourself.

Comment: This looks disorganized. Make sure you don't mess up `IFS` or `stdin` (file descriptor 0) which could be a possible cause of what you see.

Comment: Do not expect `/bin/sh` to know about arrays.

Comment: You can assign directly to the variables without the temp array: `read -r DB IP USER PWD <<< "$line"`

Comment: `<<<` is not a `sh` construct: bash/ksh/zsh

Comment: please copy/paste your code into https://shellcheck.net , fix any errors flagged, and if that doesn't solve your problem, update your question with the corrected code. Good luck.

Comment: Does `$conf_file` contain values for `choice`? If not, and you are intending for this to be interactive, you need something like `read ... choice </dev/tty`